# Why is "Improved Rune casting" listed twice in the Runecaster description?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, magic

I was just perusing one of my books (Players Guide to Faerun) and I'm reading a class ability of the Runecaster that states the following:

> **Improved Rune casting (Su)**: As a runecaster rises in level, he gains the ability to create runes that function more than once and have different kinds of triggers. These extra features increase the cost of the rune, as shown on the table.
>
> *Works When Read or Passed*: Any attempt to study, identify, or fathom a rune's meaning counts as "reading" the rune. Passing through any portal that bears a rune counts as "passing" it. To affect a target, a rune must have an unbroken line of effect to it and be within 30 feet of it.
>
> A rune that is triggered when passed can be set for almost any special condition the runecaster specifies. Runes can be set to trigger according to physical characteristics (such as height, or weight) or creature type, subtype, or race (such as draw or aberration). They can also trigger based on good, evil, law, or chaos, or a creature's patron deity. They cannot, however, be set to trigger by class, Hit Dice, or level. Runes respond to invisible creatures normally nut are not triggered by creatures that travel past them ethereally. When placing a rune with a "pass" trigger, a runecaster can specify a password or phrase that prevents the rune from triggering.

My question is that this ability seems like one solid whole, yet it's listed as being given twice, first at 3rd and then again at 8th... the normal progression of Rune Power is even interrupted to shoehorn it in... what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the Rune Casting paragraph, some new options get unlocked either at Runecaster level 3 or at Runecaster level 8.

For instance, the ability to create runes with uses per day is unlocked by the level 8 Improved Rune Casting